# how to trim wipe output with sed?

Tags: sed

i want to trim an output of wipe command with sed.
i try to use this one:

```
wipe -vx7 /dev/sdb 2>&1 | sed -u 's/.*\ \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

but it don't work for some reason.

when i use echo & sed to print the output of wipe command it works!

```
echo "/dev/sdb: 10%" | sed -u 's/.*\ \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a progress indicator. They are often output directly to the tty instead of to stdout or stderr. You may be able to use the [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) script called [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html)   ([source](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/example/unbuffer?revision=5.34&view=markup)) or some other method to create a pseudo tty. Be aware that there will probably be more junk such as `\r`, etc., that you may need to filter out.

Demonstration:

```
$ cat foo
#!/bin/sh
echo hello > /dev/tty
$ a=$(./foo)
hello
$ echo $a

$ a=$(unbuffer ./foo)
$ echo $a
hello
```